# lists with parenthesis using only javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a list (`<ol>` and `<ul>`) with parenthesis like this.

```
(1) List1
(2) List2
(3) List3
(4) List4
```

The important thing is that I need this using only javascript or jQuery without using external, internal css.

This is my code

```
$("ol").css("counter-reset", "list");
$("ol li").css("list-style", "none"); 
$("ol li:before").css({"content": "counter(list, lower-alpha) ') '", "counter-increment": "list"});
```

Comment: Tried anything ?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Why can't you just write that list in HTML? If you want to generate it in JS, where is the datasource?

Comment: show your code...

Comment: cam you provide your code?

Comment: @ANS i tried using jquery css method . but it's doesn't work

Comment: wait sir. i send you some code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i need to set the list parenthesis or brackets dynamically using jquery .

Comment: sir just send the code  no css just jquery

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the pseudo CSS tag `:before`, but it only works on newer browsers.

```css
ol {list-style-type: none}
li {counter-increment: step-counter}
li::before {
  content: "(" counter(step-counter) ")";
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>List1</li>
  <li>List2</li>
  <li>List3</li>
  <li>List4</li>
</ol>
```

## update

You mentioned that you would like to toggle it. You could do it like this

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('ol').toggleClass('numbered') // this toggles it
})
```

```css
.numbered {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.numbered li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}

.numbered li::before {
  content: "(" counter(step-counter) ")";
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>List1</li>
  <li>List2</li>
  <li>List3</li>
  <li>List4</li>
</ol>

<button>Change</button>
```

Comment: @PaulAnburaj why? the things you've put into jQuery are CSS rules. But sure, i can edit it

Comment: i need to set the list parenthesis or brackets dynamically using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You Can acheive this with the help of a line css and js code as given below :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var length = $('ol li').length;
    for(i=1;i<=length;i++){
        $('ol li:nth-child('+i+')').children('span').html('('+i+') ');
    }
});
</script>


And HTML:

<body>

<ol>
    <li><span class="list_number"></span>Stone</li>
    <li><span class="list_number"></span>Paper</li>
    <li><span class="list_number"></span>Scissor</li>
</ol>

</body>

My CSS:


<style>
ol { list-style-type:none; }
</style>

Hope This is Helpful
```

Comment: Toggling was not mentioned in the question. The initial answer should be accepted. Other questions should be asked separately.

Comment: What do you mean 'Toggling was not mentioned'

Comment: The “update” part of the question starts with “You mentioned that you would like to toggle it.” The question does not contain the word “toggle” at all or refer to any toggling, so this part does not address the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

sir you just need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ol = $('ol li');
    ol.css("list-style", "none");

    $.each(ol, function(i, el){
        $(el).text('(' + (i + 1 )+') ' + $(el).text());
    });

});
```